# How can I add 15 minutes to time and handle overflow?

Tags: java, time

I have an exercise in which I need to input hours and minutes in 24 hour format and after that the program will show me the time after 15 minutes. It doesn't work when minutes overflow after 59 minutes. When I have for example the input:

```
15
59
```

My output is:

```
15:74
```

I know that after 59 minutes at a normal clock will be `16:14`. How can I handle this case correctly?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      int hours = in.nextInt();
      int minutes = in.nextInt();

      if ( minutes == 59 ){
          hours = hours + 1;
          minutes = 00;
          minutes = minutes + 14; //because I passed 1 minute 
      }
      else{
          minutes = minutes + 15;
      }        
      System.out.printf("%d:%02d" , hours , minutes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy you should use Modulo operation like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int hours = in.nextInt();
    int minutes = in.nextInt();

    minutes = minutes + 15;
    hours += minutes / 60;
    minutes = minutes % 60;

    System.out.printf("%d:%02d", hours, minutes);
}
```

Comment: I downvoted because this solution cannot handle day overlaps. When you enter 23:59, the result should be 0:14 and not 24:14.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you don't need to program such basic things "by hand" like in C. Java provides a lot of APIs. For example the time API. See for example [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) with its method [plusMinutes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#plusMinutes-long-).

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes, but he should be trained to use APIs as well. Programming such things by hand is error prone.

Comment: Yeah! I can use them I suppose. But I think it's better to code them by myself. To learn how this things works better! :)

Comment: @LaurianHurduza The given solutions are error prone. When you enter 23:59, the result should be 0:14 and not 24:14. This is the problem by programming such things by hand, because you have to think on every special case. The API is doing that right for you, like: `LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of(hours, minutes).plusMinutes(15);`

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int hours = in.nextInt();
        int minutes = in.nextInt();

        minutes=minutes+15;
        if (minutes > 59) {
            hours++;
        }

        minutes = minutes % 60;
        hours = hours % 24;

        System.out.printf("%d:%02d", hours, minutes);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
15
59
16:14
```

**Another sample run:**

```
23
59
0:14
```

Comment: I downvoted because this solution cannot handle day overlaps. When you enter 23:59, the result should be 0:14 and not 24:14

Comment: @Bevor - Now, I've updated my answer to rectify this problem.

Comment: It has the correct behaviour now. Downvote withdrawn.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. Have a nice day!